# How to Set Single Field Dirty in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, save, field

PROBLEM: We toggle fields on form. When secondField is shown instead of firstField, then form is changed. But secondField is still marked as not dirty, because both fields remain unchanged. Showing secondField should always make it and the form (model) dirty.

RESEARCH: setDirty() method is done on whole record, setValue() acts as expected, but smells like a hack and can't be used for various field types (textfield, combobox).

QUESTION: How to manually set a single form field state changed to invoke saving its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up data state with form visualisation. By default, "field is shown" has no relation to data, so you need to explicitly create one. This can be done by changing some data on toggling, or other way round — toggling on changing data.

For example, toggling can occur on checking/unchecking a checkbox field which will represent a piece of form data (also see [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pe1)):

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    viewModel: {
        type: 'default'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            reference: 'toggle',
            itemId: 'toggle',
            boxLabel: 'Toggle',
            hidden: true
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Toggle',
            enableToggle: true,
            toggleHandler: function() {
                var form = this.up('form'),
                    checkbox = form.child('#toggle');
                checkbox.setValue(!checkbox.getValue());
                console.log(form.isDirty() ? 'Dirty!' : 'Not dirty');
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'firstField',
            fieldLabel: 'First Field',
            bind: {
                hidden: '{toggle.checked}'
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'secondField',
            fieldLabel: 'Second Field',
            bind: {
                hidden: '{!toggle.checked}'
            }
        }
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I think the question was a bit misunderstood. Two fields and their Ext.data.Model basis are given. We need to manipulate its isDirty property when toggling. Your example actually only reproduces toggling.

Comment: Well since you used the phrase "smells like a hack" I thought you are after a proper approach. The proper approach would be to accept that the `dirty` flag of a field/model is only set when there is an actual change in data (and this is done by the ExtJS behind the scenes for you). Now, what you want is to make it save data just because you've toggled (effectively changed the visibility) of some fields without changing data. Don't expect it to work and be a proper approach at the same time. Instead, use toggling in conjunction with changing some data (e.g. toggle state) like I showed above.

Comment: Hidden checkbox with toggle handler is a solution.